# Select rows per user, the last week

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having a bit of a problem with this. What I'm looking for, is to figure out, how many rows/user there is, in this week. I'm looking for a result like:

```
user_id   amount
1         3
2         2
3         0
```

From following example-table:

```
user_id   article_id
1         2
1         3
1         4
2         5
2         1
```

I can't seem to wrap my head around the problem. For the amount of articles, I've learned that `WEEKOFYEAR( post_date ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW() )` fetches the articles dates I need to sort.

Answer (score 0):

untested:

```
SELECT   user_id, count(article_id) as amount
FROM     example_table
WHERE    WEEKOFYEAR( post_date ) = WEEKOFYEAR( NOW() )
GROUP BY user_id
```